# angular tree scrolls to top on selecting a child node

Tags: angular-tree-component

i'm using @circlon/angular-tree-component for displaying treestructure
version used : 11.0.4

treeModel.update() method scrolls the tree to the top of the tree.

Note : This behaviour is not seen in previous versions

On selecting the node , tree gets scrolled to the top .

Expected Behaviour is to maintain the position